# Delete SharePoint Online site programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I'm attempting to delete a Site collection but receiving this error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Cannot delete top-level
>   site: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/teams/6KG9A4SO.'

```
    public static void DeleteSite(NetworkCredential nc, string siteToDelete)
    {
        using (var cc = new ClientContext(siteToDelete))
        {
            cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(nc.UserName, nc.SecurePassword);

            // Delete the web object  
            cc.Web.DeleteObject();
            // Execute the query to the server.  
            cc.ExecuteQuery();
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refer bellow url for site operation i.e., delete or update or create

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-retrieve-update-or-delete-sites-on-sharepoint-using-rest-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;

namespace DeleteSiteCollection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ClientContext tenantContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursite-admin.sharepoint.com/ Jump "))
            {
                SecureString password = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray())
                    password.AppendChar(c);
                tenantContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", password);
                var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);
                SpoOperation spoOperation = tenant.RemoveSite("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA Jump ");

                tenantContext.Load(spoOperation);
                tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now);
                while (!spoOperation.IsComplete)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    tenantContext.Load(spoOperation);
                    tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now);
                Console.WriteLine("Verify that site no longer show up in getSiteProperties");
                try
                {
                    SiteProperties site = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA Jump ", false);
                    tenantContext.Load(site);
                    tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("Site is not deleted");
                }
                catch (ServerException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot find the active site: " + e.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Nice verification logic too

Answer (score 2):

Delete SharePoint Site collections programmatically using CSOM with PowerShell on SharePoint online / office 365.

```
function DeleteSiteCollection(){  
try{  
    $tenant = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($ctx)  
    $removeSite = $tenant.RemoveSite("https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/CustomTest")  
    $ctx.Load($removeSite)          
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  

    Write-Host "Site Collection has been deleted"        
    Write-Host "----------------------------"  
}  
catch{  
     write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red  
}   
}
```

**Note**: The above set of operations needs to be called to get it executed.

`DeleteSiteCollection #Deletes site collection using url`

[Reference Link 1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-update-delete-or-retrieve-sharepoint-sub-sites-usin/), [Reference Link 2](http://projectservercode.com/create-and-delete-sharepoint-list-document-library-using-csom/)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to delete the root web of your site collection.

You should attempt to delete the entire site collection, you can do this via PowerShell remove-sposite by connection to the `https://tenant-admin.SharePoint.com`