# Is it possible to set a property bag value via CSOM without having tenant permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, property-bag

I'm trying to use my backend CSOM app with context of Site Collection Administrator service account to programmatically set a property bag value to store some settings for my frontend extension app.

I've tried doing it in 2 ways:

```
web.SetPropertyBagValue("name", "value");
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

and

```
web.AllProperties["name"] = "value";
web.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

but in both cases I get the error:

> {"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
> access this resource."}

Is there really no way a Site Collection Administrator could set a property bag in SharePoint Online? I'm asking this because I've had similar issue when trying to delete a site, in which case according to [a few](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228076/delete-sharepoint-online-site-programmatically) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722180/how-to-delete-sharepoint-site-collection-using-pnp-csom-programmatically) on the Internet this operation could also be done only by tenant administrator but I found a method:

```
ctx.DeleteSiteAsync()
```

which turned out to be successfully deleting a site without tenant permissions. So I hope maybe there is also a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to [NoScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script). To disable this, you must poses the SharePoint Admin or Global Admin role. It can be disabled via `Get-PnPTenantSite` or `Set-SPOSite -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0`.

For each site, this is controlled by a tenant administrator. A Site Collection Admin can do anything, including deleting the site, *except* those things covered by NoScript restrictions unless NoScript has been disabled for that particular site.

Comment: Yes, but due to [security considerations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/security-considerations-of-allowing-custom-script) of disabling `DenyAddAndCustomizePages` I'm looking if there's any other way, maybe an API that's not restricted by NoScript.

Comment: You can temporarily disable it and then re-enable it, or find an alternative solution to using Property Bags. But no, there is no alternative API (otherwise what would be the point of DenyAdd...?).